# Union and get Top1 for every record..?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, union

In the below query I am trying to filter the records which has Type value of 'ABC' and 'XYZ'.

Each ca_id can have up to 3 Types.(ABC,XYZ,and ' ')

And also I have to get one empty type ,for which I am using union.

the problem is when i use union and pick top 1 ..I get 3 types for only for one ca_id at any time.and the remaining cases have 2 Types.(ABC and XYZ)

Can some one suggest ideas how to get an empty type for every ca_id record.

Thanks

```
select lo_id,ca_id,Type,Status,Category

from (

select lo_id,ca_id,Type,Status,Category

from (


select  distinct  ln.lo_id,cast.ca_id, Type,Status, 
 'Category'= case when Type='ABC' then 'ABC'
when Type='XYZ' then 'XYZ' else ' ' End

 FROM  ln                           
INNER JOIN cast ON cast.ca_id = ln.ca_id
INNER JOIN  Type ON Type.TypeId = cast .TypeId 

 ) as Q1
where  Category in ('ABC','XYZ')

union

select  top 1  lo_id,ca_id,Type,Status,(select Category where Category in (' ',null)) 
from (

select  distinct  ln.lo_id,cast.ca_id, Type,Status, 
 'Category'= case when Type='ABC' then 'ABC'
when Type='XYZ' then 'XYZ' else ' ' End

 FROM  ln   
INNER JOIN cast ON cast.ca_id = ln.ca_id
INNER JOIN  Type ON Type.TypeId = cast .TypeId
)  as Q2
) as Q3
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: @user1046415 I would think the comments are a very bad place for sample data. Try http://sqlfiddle.com/ and I bet you'll get much better results. EDIT: It looks like the comment I was referring to has been deleted.

Comment: lo_id ca_id Type Status     Category
320728 309562 ABC  Started ABC
320728 309562 Repay  Started  
320728 309562 XYZ  Started  XYZ
494613 54549 ABC  Started  ABC
494613 54549 XYZ  Started  XYZ

Comment: @user1046415 It looks like you deleted your original posting of this comment, and then just reposted it. I am not really going to be able to make sense of it because you can't format in a comment. Either edit your post, or add a comment with a link to something like SQL Fiddle (which would be more useful). Also, without knowing your table structure this question will be harder and I'd rather not have to try to figure it out based on everything used in the query. If you could show us what tables are in play, what you want from them, and what restrictions you have it would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without a union, using the row_number() function.  The following gets all records with XYZ and ABC, and only the first for other categories:

```
select lo_id, ca_id, type, status, category
from (select distinct  ln.lo_id, cast.ca_id, Type, Status, 
             (case when Type='ABC' then 'ABC'
                   when Type='XYZ' then 'XYZ'
                   else ''
              End) as category,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ca_id, type) as seqnum
      FROM  ln INNER JOIN
            cast
            ON cast.ca_id = ln.ca_id INNER JOIN
            Type
            ON Type.TypeId = cast.TypeId 
     ) t
 where TYPE in ('ABC', 'XYZ') or seqnum = 1
```

By the way, CAST and TYPE are not good names for columns and aliases, since they have other meanings in SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked..superb..I will change my table names also ..Thanks a lot once again..for ur time